# Where do I find the latest versions of skulpt.min.js and skulpt-stdlib.js from GitHub?

Tags: github, skulpt

I am looking for the latest versions of `skulpt.min.js` and `skulpt-stdlib.js` for my website. I am new to GitHub, and asked them. They said to make a new release. So I did. And I can't find the files I am looking for. Where could I find the latest releases?

Comment: skulp/skulpt-dist repo has the built javascript files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latest version of `skulpt.js` and `skulpt-stdlib.js` are now provided through [`bower`](https://bower.io/), which is a package manager that keeps track of your packages and makes sure they're up to date.

Bower can be installed with [`npm`](https://www.npmjs.com/) running the command

```
npm install -g bower
```

From there you can get `skult.js` by running this command

```
bower install skulpt
```

If you don't want to use Bower, you can download it from [here](https://github.com/skulpt/skulpt-dist/)

Or you can get it as [`.zip`](http://www.skulpt.org/static/dist/skulpt-latest.zip) or [`.tar.gz`](http://www.skulpt.org/static/dist/skulpt-latest.tar.gz)

Comment: how do I use bower? as I said I am new to GitHub

Comment: Also, I am trying to use the `input()` function but the dialog box is not coming up. Why is this?

Answer (score 1):

Here: https://github.com/skulpt/skulpt/releases/tag/0.10.0

Look in the **Downloads** section. Here's the link: https://github.com/skulpt/skulpt/archive/0.10.0.zip

Note you'll have to build the project to get the `.js` files. See this https://github.com/skulpt/skulpt#building-skulpt for details.

Comment: I downloaded that, but I can't find `skulpt.min.js` and `skulpt-stdlib.js` in it. Do I have to make these files?

Comment: @DanielHarrin As Gabriel said, you'll have to build the source files.